# how to create, access, utilize string arrays in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm new to C++ and i was wondering how you create empty sets of string arrays,
so far i have this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
int numOfStudent;
char again;


do
{       
    cout << "How many students are in the class?";
    cin >> numOfStudent;
    while (numOfStudent > 30 || numOfStudent < 5)
    {
        cout << "The number of students must be in the range 5 - 30\n";
        cout << "How many students are in the class?";
        cin >> numOfStudent;
    }


    for (int count = 1; count <= numOfStudent; count++)
        cout << "Enter the full name of student " << count << endl;
        cin >> // this is the part where i want to use an array to store

    cout << "Here is the list of students you have entered:\n";
        for (int x = 1; x <= numOfStudent; x++)
            cout << x << ".  " // and this is the part where i want to read an array and print out


cout << "\nDo you want to continue (y/n)?";
cin >> again;
} while (again == 'Y' || again == 'y');

}
```

I'm really new to C++ any suggestion and help would be much much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `std::vector<std::string>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a homework question, but even if it is, it's so basic that a code answer should help jump start you to more complex topics:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numOfStudent;
    char again;

    vector<string> students;

    do
    {
        cout << "How many students are in the class?";
        cin >> numOfStudent;
        while (numOfStudent > 30 || numOfStudent < 5)
        {
            cout << "The number of students must be in the range 5 - 30\n";
            cout << "How many students are in the class?";
            cin >> numOfStudent;
        }


        for (int count = 1; count <= numOfStudent; count++)
        {
            string name;
            cout << "Enter the full name of student " << count << endl;
            cin >> name; // this is the part where i want to use an array to store
            students.push_back(name);
        }

            cout << "Here is the list of students you have entered:\n";
        for (int x = 1; x <= numOfStudent; x++)
            cout << "Student #"<<x << " is  "<<students.at(x-1)<<"."<<endl; // and this is the part where i want to read an array and print out


            cout << "\nDo you want to continue (y/n)?";
        cin >> again;
    } while (again == 'Y' || again == 'y');

}
```

I used your code style so that my answer would be understandable to you. You should look into proper namespace usage (it's typically not advisable to do `using namespace std` but for such a small sample it's ok) and into iterators (I used your simple for loop to iterate over the vector, but `for(auto it=students.begin()...)` is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
int numOfStudent;
char again;
vector<string> students;
string student;


do
{       
    cout << "How many students are in the class?";
    cin >> numOfStudent;
    while (numOfStudent > 30 || numOfStudent < 5)
    {
        cout << "The number of students must be in the range 5 - 30\n";
        cout << "How many students are in the class?";
        cin >> numOfStudent;


    }


    for (int count = 1; count <= numOfStudent; count++)
    {   // all activities on the loop must be in the { }
        cout << "Enter the full name of student " << count << endl;
        cin >>student 
        students.push_back(student);
    }
    cout << "Here is the list of students you have entered:\n";
        for (int x = 1; x <= numOfStudent; x++)
            cout << x << ".  "<<students[i] 




cout << "\nDo you want to continue (y/n)?";
cin >> again;
} while (again == 'Y' || again == 'y');

}



This should work for you. If it does not work , use a vector iterator to read  student names from the vector.
```